# How to refresh server caching dynamically when we have the web application running in clustering environment?

Tags: web-applications, java

Consider a typical webapplication which runs on an 
application or web server in clustering mode. Let us say we have 3 
nodes in the cluster and the application is running on these 3 nodes 
and serving all the user requests. There are some property values that 
are stored in database and instead of going to database every single 
time this application maintains a cache at server side, at node level, 
and stores these property values in the cache and serves the values 
from the cache.

Now we update on of the property value in the database. How do we 
ensure that this updated value gets reflected in cache across all the 
nodes?

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to do it I think.
Either the cache become at the cluster level or you have to broadcast the invalidation of an entry to each server.

I would say there is a 3rd way which could be a centralized database where each invalid key is kept and the server check that database to ensure the key is still valid (but it's a little bit more complex to implement)

So cache level at the cluster is certainly the easiest but it really depends on why you have the cache server in place (if it's just a replication of the main database then this solution is not valid).